# Measurement and localisation in SwiftUI Text and TextField views

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

Using Measurement with a Text view is simple enough but when it comes to TextField I’m a bit confused about what to expect, or what’s good practice for internationalisation and localisation.

The simulator App Region is set to United States so my first Text view will correctly show 2 in.

The Text view I use length.value to access the Double component of the measurement and this correctly shows 5.0.

Now we get to the TextField. Because I’ve used $length.value for the binding it will also display 5.0. I used .centimetres in my length property because that’s my region but what if someone is using a US region?

How do I make the Double localised?

```
import SwiftUI
struct SomeView: View {
    
    @State private var length: Measurement<UnitLength> = Measurement(value: 5, unit: .centimeters)

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Text(length.formatted())
            Text(String(length.value))
            TextField("length", value: $length.value, format: .number)
        }
        .font(.system(size: 82))
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I did look at this question [How to bind Measurement with UI in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62258695/1573326) but a. it doesn't address the localisation, and b. it's over 3 years old and seems a bit outdated.

I also checked out this answer on Hackingwithswift https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/i-guess-this-code-is-silly-but-how-to-make-it-smarter-bindings-unitconversion/12512/12537

### Update

So after re-thinking my question a little, this is what Ive come up with. This includes my SwiftData Model. This works ok but I'm unsure how I should enable the user to change the unit e.g. using a Picker.

I tried adding a unitType var to my model and using a switch statement for Locale.current.measurementSystem like @Joakim Danielson's answer below but that had issues with unitType being a get only property or something.. I'm not sure on the Picker with the item.length.unit as the selection binding and the ForEach with the item.length.unit.symbol.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        HStack {
                            TextField("Length", value: Binding(
                                get: {
                                    item.length?.value ?? 0
                                },
                                set: {
                                    item.length = Measurement(value: $0, unit: .meters)
                                }), format: .number)
                            Text(item.length?.unit.symbol ?? "")
                        }
                        .font(.system(size: 82))
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.length ?? Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 0.0, unit: .meters), format: .measurement(width: .abbreviated, numberFormatStyle: .number))
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(length: Measurement(value: .random(in: 0...99), unit: .meters))
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

@Model
final class Item {
    var lengthMeters: Double? = nil
    @Transient var length: Measurement<UnitLength>? {
        get {
            if let lengthMeters {
                return Measurement<UnitLength>(value: lengthMeters, unit: .meters)
            } else { return nil }
        }
        set {
            lengthMeters = newValue?.value
        }
    }
    
    init(length: Measurement<UnitLength>) {
        self.length = length
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind Measurement with UI in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258695/how-to-bind-measurement-with-ui-in-swiftui)

Comment: No. I did see that but it doesn't address the localisation, and b. it's over 3 years old and seems a bit outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to always convert the start value to the unit type of the users locale.

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State private var length: Measurement<UnitLength>

    init(input: Measurement<UnitLength>) {
        self._length = State(wrappedValue: input.converted(to: UnitLength(forLocale: .current)))
    }
    //...
}
```

This is straight forward but will give us the default length type for the locale which for instance is meters for the metric system so when calling the view like this

```
SomeView(input: Measurement(value: 3, unit: .inches))
```

the textfield will contain "0.0762" since it is in meters

One way to work around this is to use the property `measurementSystem` on the locale and then set our preferred type depending on the system

Here is one example

```
init(input: Measurement<UnitLength>) {
    var unitType: UnitLength
    switch Locale.current.measurementSystem {
    case .metric:
        unitType = UnitLength.centimeters
    default:
        unitType = UnitLength.inches
    }

    self._length = State(wrappedValue: input.converted(to: unitType))
}
```

And now the TextField will contain a value in centimetres instead of the default meters

---

**Update**

If you want to let the user to select what measurement type to use I don't think you can do that automatically based on the users Locale or similar. Instead you need to hard code the available options per measurement system

An example

```
func availableUnitLengths() -> [UnitLength] {
    switch Locale.current.measurementSystem {
    case .metric:
        return [.centimeters, .decimeters, .meters]
    default:
        return [.inches, .feet, .yards]
    }
}
```

Then you can use this function in a picker

```
@State private var unitLength: UnitLength = UnitLength(forLocale: .current)
//...
var body: some View {
    //...
    Picker("Length type", selection: $unitLength) {
       ForEach(availableUnitLengths(), id: \.self) {
           Text($0.symbol).tag($0)
       }
    }
    //...
}
```

And if you want to use this picker selection in a view I suggest you use `Double` for the property and only use `Measurment` to convert between length types when the picker selection is changed

```
struct SomeView: View {
    let length: Measurement<UnitLength> = Measurement(value: 3, unit: .meters)
    @State private var unitLength: UnitLength = UnitLength(forLocale: .current)
    @State var value: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Picker("Length type", selection: $unitLength) {
                ForEach(availableUnitLengths(), id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.symbol).tag($0)
                }
            }
            Text(String(value))
            TextField("length", value: $value, format: .number)
        }
        .onChange(of: unitLength, initial: true) {_, unitType in
            value = length.converted(to: unitType).value
        }
    }
}
```

I use `let length ...` to simplify the example, it represents the input to the view and for the "output" you need to convert `value` back to meters.

Comment: Great example. In my real life code length isn't a state property but rather an @Transient var in my SwiftData model and so here I think @Sweeper's idea to use `.converted(to: .init(forLocale: Locale.current, usage: .person))` may be simpler

Comment: Well that is what my first solution does but I omitted the optional parameter `usage` because I didn’t know which one was most appropriate for you.

Comment: I updated my question - I think I have a better idea what I should be asking, or trying to do.

Comment: @TimD I have updated my answer with an idea on how to move forward.

Comment: For my use case it doesn't make much sense to only show length types for one locale, but to allow the user to select between inches and centimetres with the default set to their locale. So here it looks like I'd keep the Picker binding as is but probably hard code inches and centimetres in the Picker. I thought this might work `Text("in").tag(.inches)` but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the preferred unit of the current locale by using [`init(forLocale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dimension/4020114-init). I would recommend also specifying a usage ([`init(forLocale:usage:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/unitlength/4020255-init)).

After getting the preferred unit, you just convert "5cm" to that unit and bind `length.value` to the text field.

```
@State private var length: Measurement<UnitLength> = 
    Measurement(value: 5, unit: .centimeters)
        .converted(to: .init(forLocale: Locale.current, usage: .person))

var body: some View {
    // perhaps you should also show the user what the unit actually is
    LabeledContent("Length (Unit: \(length.unit.symbol))") {
        TextField("Length", value: $length.value, format: .number)
    }
    .font(.system(size: 82))
}
```

You can easily convert `length` back to cm (or whatever else you like) when necessary.

Comment: In my real life code length isn't a @State property, it's a @Transient var in my SwiftData model, so before I go hacking that up I thought I'd try using the `.converted(to: .init(forLocale: Locale.current, usage: .person))` in the Text view, this is what I've done `Text(String(length.converted(to: .init(forLocale: Locale.current, usage: .person)).value))`

Comment: yeah that's what I've done and I've got .precision(). It feels a little 'hacky' `            Text(length.converted(to: .init(forLocale: Locale.current, usage: .person)).value, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0...1)))`.. if I put a Slider in I can see the rounding change a little as the first Text will adapt between inches and feet but obviously the second will stay in inches

Comment: @TimD What did you expect to happen otherwise? Of course it feels "hacky" when you put it in an uneditable `Text`, because it's a `Text`. Remember that you are making a `TextField` here. Why would anyone want a `TextField` that changes units depending on what you entered? Specify a `usage:` for whatever this is measuring and stick with it.

Comment: @TimD I would even say that `TextField`s don't need to be localised this way. `TexField` is *input*, not *output* like `Text`. You can totally just allow the user to choose their favourite unit instead with a `Picker` (then perhaps set the default selection to the preferred unit of that `Locale`).

Comment: I think that may have been a part of my issue - I think I'm a little more clearer on what I need to be looking for - asking the right question. I think you're totally right re the TextField just handling the value with no locale and using a Picker to change the unit... which I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: @TimD Huh, I didn't expect making a unit picker would be this difficult until you mentioned it. `UnitLength` is a class that is neither `Hashable` nor `Identifiable`, which makes it very difficult to work with in SwiftUI. You need to make your own `UnitLength` type (perhaps an enum), and then use the unit symbol as the raw value so that you can convert between the built-in `UnitLength` and your own enum.